# Phoenix - Flash message not showing for specific controller action

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Inside `page_controller.ex` I have an index and a profile action like so.

```
defmodule Kappamon.PageController do
  use Kappamon.Web, :controller

  plug Kappamon.Plugs.RequireLogin when action in [:profile]

  def index(conn, _params) do
    render conn, "index.html"
  end

  def profile(conn, _params) do
    render conn, "profile.html"
  end
end
```

The only difference in these two actions is that the `RequireLogin` plug checks if a user is logged in by checking `conn.assigns[:current_user]`.

Here is the plug:

```
defmodule Kappamon.Plugs.RequireLogin do
  import Plug.Conn
  import Phoenix.Controller

  alias Kappamon.Router.Helpers

  def init(_opts) do
  end

  def call(conn, _) do
    if conn.assigns[:current_user] do
      conn
    else
      conn
      |> put_flash(:error, "Sorry, you have to be logged in first.")
      |> redirect(to: Helpers.page_path(conn, :index))
      |> halt()
    end
  end
end
```

The `put_flash` method works fine when I redirect to `:index` however when I redirect to `:profile`, the flash message is `nil`.

Here is the controller action where the issue is occuring.

```
def delete(conn, _param) do
  user = Ecto.Changeset.change(conn.assigns[:current_user],
                               spotify_refresh: nil,
                               spotify_access: nil)

  case Repo.update(user) do
    {:ok, _} ->
      conn
      |> put_flash(:info, "Successfully disconnected from Spotify!")
      |> redirect(to: page_path(conn, :profile))
    {:error, _} ->
      conn
      |> put_flash(:error, "There was an error disconnecting Spotify. Sorry about that.")
      |> redirect(to: page_path(conn, :profile))
  end
end
```

If I change `:profile` to `:index` above, the flash message displays.

Comment: can you add the plug to the question?

Comment: @sevenseacat I have added the plug

Comment: Does the :profile action uses the very same layout, that has flash displaying in it?

Comment: @PatNowak Yes that file was copied and pasted